# Click menu with children

Tags: jquery, list, menu, click

I am looking for some sort of jQuery click menu that will open up another `ul` if the clicked `li` element has children - something like this.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href"#">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href"page1.html">Item 1 child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href"page2.html">Item 1 child 2</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href"#">Item 1 child 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href"#">Item 1 child 3 child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href"page3.html">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href"page4.html">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

So when I click **"Item 1"** it will open up the new list and if I click **"Item 1 child 3"** it will open yet another list and so forth and so on.

I think I once saw some about `.next` but I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   $(this).closest("li").children("ul").toggle();
});​

$("a").click();//quick hack to hide all children to start with (if desired)
```

[See here for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/FTdxS/3/)

[Here is an example with a sliding effect](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/FTdxS/10/) (as hinted in comments)

---

**NOTES**

Using the `.children` function will mean that all "sub-expansions" will be "retained" once the parent is re-expanded - to me this seems like the natural behaviour.

If you would prefer that closing a parent reset all sub expansions to also be closed the next time the parent is expanded, then you can use the `.find` method in replace of `.children`

Also, it should be considered that this code will apply to all A links on the page, if you need to be more specific about which A links this applied to you should change the selector. One example to only include A links within a UL element might look like this:

```
$("ul a").click(...
```

Comment: This actually seems to do what I am in the look for! :)

Forgive my stupidity - can this be used together with f.x. slideDown / slideUp

Comment: @MortenHagh: the `.toggle` function takes care of checking for the current visibility of the element. if you want custom show/hide code then you will need to split out the code.. [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/FTdxS/9/)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very very much :) May all that is good come to you!

Comment: Just one more question - can it be extended to close the open menu, when another parent is clicked?

Comment: @MortenHagh: Not sure what you mean? Try changing `children` to `find` - is that what you want?

Comment: If I click Item 1 this opens up as it should. What I want then is that if I now click Item 2, the Item 1 menu will close and Item 2 will open...

Comment: @MortenHagh: [Here you go, because I am so kind](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/FTdxS/23/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery accordion plugin would be an ideal approach to your requirement.
More details of how to implement it, can be found here
[jQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

Answer (score 0):

Not the full implementation, but this should help I guess :

```
$("list").click(function(){
  $(this).find("ul").show();
});
```

That is, you can use "find()" to get the children elements.

EDIT: If you want the fisrt occurrence then use the "first()" api.

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/first/