# use the jquery find() method to hide childs when a parent is selected

Tags: jquery, methods, find

I have the following code which i have found from here [Click menu with children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349042/click-menu-with-children) :

```
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        var children = $(this).closest("li").children("ul");
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.slideUp();//use custom hide here
        }
        else {
             children.slideDown();//use custom show here
             }
         });
    $("li ul").hide(); //quick hack to hide all children to start with
```

I want each time i click on a parent, all the childrens of other parents to get hidden.

I create my code here http://jsfiddle.net/FTdxS/42/ but i can not figure out how can i make the children of other parents to hide when i click on a specific parent.

I know that i have to use the find method but i can not understand it.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("li").children("ul").slideToggle().end()
           .siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FTdxS/43/)

Comment: thanks, is there is way to speed up the slide so it look instantly?

Comment: on more question if you know: if i have a parent that have the class="active", when the page load how can i show only this parent child at the beginning. And when i click on another father link the behavior to continue as before. I try this http://jsfiddle.net/FTdxS/46/ but all the parent child are shown at beginning

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the else condition :

```
    $('li ul:visible').not(children).slideUp()
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FTdxS/44/

Comment: thanks, your solution is also working well.   
 
Do you know if there is way to speed up the slide so it look instantly?